# what is the best way to learn react?

Tags: reactjs

what's the best way/resources to learn react? i have some background in HTML/CSS/JS/python.

Comment: this question is very opinionated, there are no "best ways" and it is not allowed to ask for tutorials on stack overflow.  Just go to the react homepage and start there. Voted to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply start your first React journey with CRA(Create React App).
There are many steps to build React project like Webpack, babel or something but if you use CRA, you don't have to do it. You can simply start with your first React project with it.

Here is a link.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

and you should learn usage of React in here
https://reactjs.org/

This is another tip is that if you wanna learn React.js fast, you should know how javaScript runs and know how to make a component using html, css first. cuz one of the reasons People use React is that it helps people to make reusable UI component with JSX but usage JSX code is almost same with using plain html, css code.

I hope you find a solution :D